# Unable to load the dropdown list on a kendo window from a method using Webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services, kendo-ui

On clicking Edit button on a Page a method is triggered and a window which uses a kendo template is opened . One of the control on the kendo window is Kendo dropdown list which needs to have values comming from the webmethod.The error i am getting on clicking of the edit button is 'Object doesn't support property or method 'slice'. Below is my code for the Edit button.

```
function edit(item) {
var editTemplate = kendo.template($("#editTemplate").html());
var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
var selectedNode = treeview.select();
var node = treeview.dataItem(selectedNode);
$("<div/>")
    .html(editTemplate({ node: node}))
    .appendTo("body")
    .kendoWindow({
        modal: true,
        activate:function(){


            $("#roles").kendoDropDownList({
                dataTextField: "Countryname",
                dataValueField: "CountryId",
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/Services/MenuServices.asmx/getcountries",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // tells the web service to serialize JSON
                            type: "POST", //use HTTP POST request as the default GET is not allowed for ASMX
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            },
        deactivate: function () {
            this.destroy();
        }
    })
 .on("click", ".k-primary", function (e) {     
    var dialog = $(e.currentTarget).closest("[data-role=window]").getKendoWindow();
    var textbox = dialog.element.find(".k-textbox");
    var Id = $('#ID').val();
    node.set("id", Id);
    dialog.close();
    var treenode = treeview.dataSource.get(itemid);
    treenode.set("id", Id);
    treenode.ID = Id;



    console.log(JSON.stringify(treenode));
        })
```

}

IS there any property for Kendo window that triggers this service when its opened.Right now i am using activate event but its not working.tried using 'Open' event also.

Thanks

Comment: Could you include a fiddle? It's hard to find the issue from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the Schema part to the datasource and it worked.

```
schema: {
                        data: function (response) {
                            return JSON.parse(response.d); // ASMX services return JSON in the following format { "d": <result> }. 
                        },
                        model: { // define the model of the data source. Required for validation and property types.
                            id: "CountryId",
                            fields: {
                                CountryId: { editable: false, nullable: false, type: "string" },
                                Countryname: { editable: true, nullable: true, type: "string" },
                               }
                        },
                    },
```